# When new versions of ECMAScript are released, does JavaScript inherit any of those changes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I recently was reading about the ECMAScript 6, and I noticed that the syntax is starting to look and feel a little bit like Swift, and a little less like JavaScript.

When new versions come out, what does that mean for JavaScript?

Comment: It isn't that ECMAScript looks less like JavaScript (they are effectively the same thing) - more that today's JavaScript is a little different from yesterday's. When new features are added, most JavaScript implementations will adopt the new features. This is happening in browsers and Node right now.

Comment: What's "*javascript*" for you? Do you mean Mozilla's JavaScript implementation?

Comment: That the standard was called _ECMAScript_ instead of _JavaScript_  has a historical reason. But everything that is standardized in  _ECMAScript_ specification will be adapted by the various _JavaScript Engine_  implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMASCript is basically the standards process and what the language is called in that standards process.  "Javascript" is the more common term of usage that describes specific implementations - it does not describe a different language.  So Javascript in Firefox is a specific implementation.  It is up to the maker of a given implementation how closely and how quickly they will follow changes to the standard.

ES6 features are already appearing in the current Javascript implementations of Firefox, Chrome, node.js, Edge, etc...  None have all the features yet.

---

If memory serves me, the term "Javascript" originally had some trademark issues so when the language specification went into the standards process, they decided to use a name that had no trademark issues even though the name in use in the marketplace was already "Javascript".  If you'll recall, Microsoft first called their implementation "Jscript".  The name differences nowadays are not meant to imply a different language, just a different moniker used to describe them.

---

If you want to program in ES6 now, you can either find a Javascript implementation that already supports the features you want to use or you can get a transpiler like [BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/) that will convert most ES6 code to ES5 compatible code that will run in current ES5 Javascript engines.  The idea there is that you code in ES6, compile it to ES5 and run the ES5 in your favorite JS engine.

For reference, here is a [table of ES6 feature support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) in many of the common JS engines.

Comment: Naming it JavaScript instead of ECMAScript would have been a problem at this time not because JavaScript had a trademark on its name, but because of the conflict between Netscape and Microsoft, Microsoft would have never participated in the standard called JavaScript and Netscape not to JScript. The idea was that a standard for the web scripting language is created by a  neutral institution. _ECMAScript_   was a working title for the standard that remained until now.

Comment: @t.niese - that is also true (the fierce competiton between Netscape/Microsoft at the time), but "Javascript" was a trademarked name at the time owned by Sun Microsystems (now owned by Oracle) and licensed by Netscape (now Mozilla). The standards process attempts to avoid legally encumbered names so it was natural to not use a trademarked name. You are also correct that picking a "neutral" name with no brand affiliation likely would have helped get others like Microsoft to be involved in the standards process.

Comment: Sorry I think I expressed it the wrong way. I didn't want to say that JavaScript didn't have a trademark, but that its trademark most likely was not the initial problem. I believe that even if Sun would have dropped the trademark, Microsoft would not have participated. Anyway, the actual reason is only known by the people that made that decision at that time.

Answer (score 1):

**ECMAScript 2015** (ES6, JavaScript 6, etc) is the new version of the language, it doesn't matter the name and it doesn't matter the platform.

What it matters, is that browsers and Node.js implement the new features and syntax at their own pace, so you will find some features already integrated in Edge that Node.js doesn't have yet.

The [ECMAScript compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) will tell you more about it.

What all this means to your code? Nothing.

You can keep writing your "old good" JavaScript with no problem and everything will work just fine.

Also, if you want to write JS with the new syntax and use all those cool new features making them compatible with your old code you can use a transpiler like [Babel.js](https://babeljs.io/).

**ECMAScript 2015** is here and is to stay, so you better embrace it and become part of this as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this in another (more practical) angle,  u can take a look at

Es6 transpiration tools, like babeljs: https://babeljs.io
Es6 support on different platforms: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/